# stop propagation not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

My collapsible list works fine with IE 11, Chrome 46, Opera 32 and Safari but not in Firefox 40.

Desired function:

When clicking the first li-item (=country) the hidden ul below will be visible. The ul contains at least one li which can contain a hidden ul and so on. Clicking them as they get visible will make the whole branch visible like this:

Before first click:

```
...
Mexico
...
```

After first click

```
...
Mexico
    Chichen-Itza
...
```

And after clicking "Chichen-Itza"

```
...
Mexico
    Chichen-Itza
        Doe, John
...
```

Clicking "Doe, John" will load personal data in another div and the collapsible list will be unaffected.

This works fine in every browser except for Firefox where the propagation (?) continues despite my efforts to stop it. In Firefox this happens:

Before first click:

```
...
Mexico
...
```

After first click

```
...
Mexico
    Chichen-Itza
...
```

And after clicking "Chichen-Itza"

```
...
Mexico
...
```

The "propagation" has clicked the first item again and thereby closed it. If I click "Mexico" once more I get:

```
...
Mexico
    Chichen-Itza
        Doe, John
...
```

So my conclusion is that everything works fine except for the extra click the first item recieves. I have been trying to find an answer to this problem but failed and my skills in javascript are limited.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<ul class="CL">
    ...
    <li class=" CLclosed" id="li_40" onclick="CLtoggle ('li_40', 'ul_40');"><label>Mexico</label>
        <ul class="CL" id="ul_40" style="display: none;">
            <li class=" CLclosed" id="li_41" onclick="CLtoggle('li_41', 'ul_41');"><label>Chichen-Itza</label>
                <ul id="ul_41" style="display: none;">
                    <li><a onclick="get('indi.php?xid=4857','text_pd')"> Doe, John </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function CLtoggle(li_x,ul_x) {
    var li = document.getElementById(li_x);
    var open = li.className.match(/(^| )CLclosed( |$)/);
    li.className = li.className.replace(/(^| )CL(open|closed)( |$)/, '');
    li.className += ' CL' + (open ? 'open' : 'closed');
    var ul = document.getElementById(ul_x);
    ul.style.display = (open ? 'block' : 'none');
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

Why is only Firefox bothered and the other browsers are not?

Comment: Firefox doesn't have a global `event`.  It's passed as a parameter to event handlers instead.

Comment: Thank you Pointy. I am not sure how to pass the event. If I change to onclick="CLtoggle ('li_40', 'ul_40',event);" and add a third parameter to the function will that be enough?.

Comment: Yes, because "onxxx" type event handlers are treated so that the `event` is passed in as a parameter with that name, so you can pass it on. On other browsers, that will serve as a reference to the global `event`, so it should work there too.

Comment: Thanks again Pointy. I have changed my code and it now works perfectly in all my browsers!